# ANDROID: starting activity with button click; the button has a background; excess memory issue

Tags: android, button, android-activity, buttonclick

**I think i have been able to resolve my MAIN problem - thanks folks for help** However, I am getting the following warning / error messages in my logcat:

```html
06-03 10:52:25.420 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
06-03 10:52:25.420 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1832 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
06-03 10:52:25.420 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0258
06-03 10:52:25.420 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
06-03 10:52:25.420 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1832 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
06-03 10:52:25.420 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0058
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemService, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 512: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x004b
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.stopLockTask, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 248: Landroid/app/Activity;.stopLockTask ()V
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00b9
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 260 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00f1
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 492: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0101
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onVisibleBehindCanceled, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 168: Landroid/app/Activity;.onVisibleBehindCanceled ()V
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0111
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 172: Landroid/app/Activity;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0137
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 260 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x019a
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 213 (Landroid/media/session/MediaController;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01b2
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2020 (Landroid/widget/Toolbar;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01bc
06-03 10:52:25.435 2365-2490/? I/CrashAnrDetector: onPackageUpdateFinished : xxx
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.releaseInstance, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 179: Landroid/app/Activity;.releaseInstance ()Z
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x02dd
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onActivityReenter, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 112: Landroid/app/Activity;.onActivityReenter (ILandroid/content/Intent;)V
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x02f4
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 564: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
06-03 10:52:25.435 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0349
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View; from Lyyy/MainActivity;)
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2580: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0432
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getVoiceInteractor, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 91: Landroid/app/Activity;.getVoiceInteractor ()Landroid/app/VoiceInteractor;
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0490
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 26 (Landroid/app/ActivityManager$TaskDescription;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x055b
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.startActionMode, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 223: Landroid/app/Activity;.startActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0596
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.showAssist, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 218: Landroid/app/Activity;.showAssist (Landroid/os/Bundle;)Z
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x05d8
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.postponeEnterTransition, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 176: Landroid/app/Activity;.postponeEnterTransition ()V
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x05e3
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 576: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
06-03 10:52:25.440 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0672
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 182: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0787
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 57 (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x07a1
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 260 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x07e8
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: DexOpt: resolve class illegal access: Lyyy/MainActivity; -> Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityDonut;
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreateView, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2356: Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityDonut;.onCreateView (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x082c
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDirs, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 571: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getExternalFilesDirs (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0882
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionManager', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1829 (Landroid/transition/TransitionManager;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x093e
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onProvideReferrer, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 152: Landroid/app/Activity;.onProvideReferrer ()Landroid/net/Uri;
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x097e
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.doReallyStop (Z)V from Lyyy/MainActivity;)
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2582: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.doReallyStop (Z)V
06-03 10:52:25.445 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x09ab
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 496: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x09f5
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.showLockTaskEscapeMessage, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 221: Landroid/app/Activity;.showLockTaskEscapeMessage ()V
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0a05
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getContentTransitionManager, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 66: Landroid/app/Activity;.getContentTransitionManager ()Landroid/transition/TransitionManager;
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0a0b
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 57 (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;) in Lyyy/MainActivity;
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0ac7
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getReferrer, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 80: Landroid/app/Activity;.getReferrer ()Landroid/net/Uri;
06-03 10:52:25.450 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0b3b
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemServiceName, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 585: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getSystemServiceName (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0bb8
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isVoiceInteractionRoot, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 104: Landroid/app/Activity;.isVoiceInteractionRoot ()Z
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0be0
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalMediaDirs, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 572: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getExternalMediaDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0c68
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getMediaController, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 74: Landroid/app/Activity;.getMediaController ()Landroid/media/session/MediaController;
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0cac
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getSearchEvent, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 83: Landroid/app/Activity;.getSearchEvent ()Landroid/view/SearchEvent;
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d2b
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.onReallyStop ()V from Lyyy/MainActivity;)
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2616: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.onReallyStop ()V
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d6b
06-03 10:52:25.455 5258-5258/? D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isVoiceInteraction, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 103: Landroid/app/Activity;.isVoiceInteraction ()Z
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0ddb
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestVisibleBehind, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 183: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestVisibleBehind (Z)Z
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e40
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 216: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e55
06-03 10:52:25.455 7149-7149/xxx I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAndRemoveTask, referenced from method xxx.MainActivity.access$super
```

**What I have?**
Main activity - having 7 buttons, each button has an image as a background. All the buttons are clickable, and on click of each button a new activity is started. So, if I click button 1, then activity1 is started, on clicking button2, activity2 is started and so on. Each of the new activities, i.e., activity1, activity2, ... activity7 also have an image, which the app is taking from the mipmap folder.

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="xxx.MainActivity">

   <Button
       android:layout_width="103dp"
       android:layout_height="82dp"
       android:id="@+id/btn_inside"
       android:layout_below="@+id/LL_subheading1"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:background="@mipmap/pic_small_inside"
       style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
       android:clickable="true"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="103dp"
       android:layout_height="82dp"
       android:id="@+id/btn_on_the_side1"
       android:layout_below="@+id/LL_subheading2"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:background="@mipmap/pic_small_on_the_side1"
       style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
       android:clickable="true"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="103dp"
       android:layout_height="82dp"
       android:id="@+id/btn_on_the_side3"
       android:layout_below="@+id/LL_subheading2"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:background="@mipmap/pic_small_on_the_side3"
       style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
       android:clickable="true"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="103dp"
       android:layout_height="82dp"
       android:id="@+id/btn_on_the_side2"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_on_the_side1"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:background="@mipmap/pic_small_on_the_side2"
       style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
       android:clickable="true"/>

   

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7;

  @
  Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    OnClickButtonListener();
  }

  public void OnClickButtonListener() {
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent_1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity_1.class);
        startActivity(intent_1);
      }
    });


    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent_2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity_2.class);
        startActivity(intent_2);
      }
    });

    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent_3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity_3.class);
        startActivity(intent_3);
      }
    });

    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_4);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent_4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity_4.class);
        startActivity(intent_4);
      }
    });

    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_5);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent_5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity_5.class);
        startActivity(intent_5);
      }
    });

    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_6);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent_6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity_6.class);
        startActivity(intent_6);
      }
    });

    btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_7);
    btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent_7 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity_7.class);
        startActivity(intent_7);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**logcat**

```js
05 - 25 23: 43: 17.209 17042 - 17042 < XX > W / < YY > : threadid = 1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group = 0x41e4e700)
05 - 25 23: 43: 17.209 17042 - 17042 < XX > E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java: 596)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java: 444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java: 832)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java: 2988)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java: 602)
at android.view.View. < init > (View.java: 3563)
at android.widget.TextView. < init > (TextView.java: 881)
at android.widget.Button. < init > (Button.java: 108)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton. < init > (AppCompatButton.java: 62)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton. < init > (AppCompatButton.java: 58)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java: 105)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java: 972)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java: 1030)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java: 44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java: 690)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java: 761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 354)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java: 276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java: 136)
at abcpqr.red.MainActivity_1.onCreate(MainActivity_1.java: 21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java: 159)
t android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1316)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05 - 25 23: 43: 25.074 17042 - 17042 < XX > I / Process: Sending signal.PID: 17042 SIG: 9
```

**What is my problem?**
I am having the error of excess memory.

**Graphical representation of my problem**
Please see the image below: [image]

Please could somebody help me? Is there a better way of approaching such a problem?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the actual code for your `MainActivity`, and also paste the complete error log so we can examine it.

Comment: I had a similar issue when making an app, fixed by setting resource drawable = null on all images in closing. Then when onResume reload the resources.  Or ad an alternative mthod it maybe better to use fragments for this, would save you with the memory issues you're having.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla - thanks - i have added xml and java of the main activity, and also logcat.

Comment: @Geoff - does my edit help?

Comment: Whats most likely is your images are quite large and are being compressed down for the buttons - thus taking more memory. 14 small images shouldn't take much memory. Either shrink them down to the smallest you can have them on the highest density screen they'll be used on or clear out in onPause and in onResume reload them.

Comment: I have had the same bloody problem. Got me pissed for quite a while and then I realized that my images were in too high resolution ( I think I had 5 of them 1024x1024), and they caused the app to crash on some slower devices. Try to adjust the size of the images better. If they're too large, surely that's causing the crash.

Comment: @TheGeoExpertTGE did my below pointers resolve your issue?  If so, please mark as answer, if not, then what happens after you've made those changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make sure your images are the best size for the highest density they'll be displayed on. (If they're huge images that are being compressed they're taking up a lot of extra memory).

2) Change all your buttons to ImageButtons, then clear out memory after during the activity `onStop()`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        // This controls the images and makes sure 
        // they're not using memory once the activity is closed
        Drawable d = imageButton1.getDrawable();
        if (d != null) d.setCallback(null);
        imageButton1.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
```

Just remember that when you want to reload the activity, you'll have to redeclare your imageButton src.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        imageButton1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.pic_small_inside);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i could manage this to work just by reducing the size of the images.thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Your always best off clearing images out so you're not using excess memory when its not needed. Still is the answer as above though. Glad it helped.

Comment: thanks @Geoff - i am getting some warnings - pl can you help? (note that i am new to android, and do this just as a side hobby - but am really fascinated with it!). my new logcat is at the beginning of my original post.

Comment: @TheGeoExpert TGE I'm at work now so cant spend time looking into this, you're best off marking this as resolved, then searching for some of the terms in logcat in google, failing that make a new question and go around it that way - will get new hits then.

Comment: @TheGeoExper TGE There should be a tick just under the up and down arrow left hand side of my answer :)